# Regular Expressions: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, regex

i put this regex into my validator, and when i go to the page the console shows me the following error:
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

```
.attr("regex", "^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?   [13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$quot;)
```

Any Help?

Thx!

Comment: Sometimes you have to look allllll the way to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `"` at the end of the 2nd parameter.  It shows as `quot;`

This is strange because I would expect to see `&quot;` (HTML entity).  I expect you already filtered out the `&`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `quot;` for `"` at the end of the line.